# What is the difference between superscalar and pipelined architectures?

Tags: architecture, cpu

They seem exactly the same to me, but the wikipedia page on Superscalar CPU architectures says  "While a superscalar CPU is typically also pipelined, pipelining and superscalar architecture are considered different performance enhancement techniques."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wikipedia articles for [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) and [supercalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar) explain these quite good.

Simply put, a pipeline starts the execution of the next instruction before the first has completed - but instructions are executed still in series and in order.

A superscalar architecture can start two or more instructions in parallel in one core, and  independent instructions may get executed out-of-order.

Comment: You could add that to be able to start several instructions in parallel, a superscalar processor has necessarily several execution units. And that both pipelining and superscalar are enterily managed at the processor level, the binary code doesn't have to contain specific instructions to enable them.